# Deleting SnapShopt files on iMac High Sierra 10.13.6

Tags: linux

How do I determine the machine directory for host? I need to delete Snap Shot files on iMac High Sierra 10.13.6

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.